# Select column values linked to exact set of values in another column

Tags: postgresql, join, relational-division

Given the below `chats_users` table in Postgres 9.5, with integer columns `chat_id` and `user_id`, I want to find the `chat_id` associated with an ***exact*** set of `user_id`s, for example:

```
user_id IN (1, 3)    => chat_id 2
user_id IN (1, 2, 3) => chat_id 1
user_id IN (1, 2)    => no result
```

Is there a simple join to return the correct `chat_id`?

```
|-----------------------|
| chats_users           |
|-----------|-----------|
| chat_id 1 | user_id 1 |
| chat_id 1 | user_id 2 |
| chat_id 1 | user_id 3 |
| chat_id 2 | user_id 1 |
| chat_id 2 | user_id 3 |
| chat_id 3 | user_id 2 |
| chat_id 3 | user_id 3 |
|-----------------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a `PRIMARY KEY` on `(chat_id, user_id)` - or a `UNIQUE` constraint plus `NOT NULL` on both columns.

To allow **any number of IDs**, use a 1-dimensional array parameter:

```
SELECT chat_id
FROM   chats_users c
WHERE  user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::int[])
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = array_length('{1,2,3}'::int[], 1)
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   chats_users
   WHERE  chat_id = c.chat_id
   AND    user_id <> ALL ('{1,2,3}'::int[])
   );
```

Typically, in function or prepared statements, you provide the array parameter only *once*. Example for prepared statement:

```
PREPARE foo(int[]) AS
SELECT chat_id
FROM   chats_users c
WHERE  user_id = ANY ($1)
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = array_length($1, 1)  -- all required user_id
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   chats_users
   WHERE  chat_id = c.chat_id
   AND    user_id <> ALL ($1)  -- no additional user_id
   );
```

Tests:

```
EXECUTE foo('{1,2,3}');  -- 1
EXECUTE foo('{1,3}');    -- 2
EXECUTE foo('{2,3}');    -- 3
EXECUTE foo('{1,2}');    -- empty
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2f518874a3293c4ef5a7299a68929cbc)*
Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73abc/2).

That's basically the first solution by Martin in this related answer on SO (with some modifications to fit your case):

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774879/939860)

There are faster solutions for a small, given number of IDs.