# Should I write a scalar function or a setof returning function for an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE which can return at most one row?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions, functions

I want to embed certain `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements into a function, to enhance re-usability. These functions have in common that the are manipulating a single row (if it exists).

An example is the following function:

```
create function my_table_delete(_identifier int) returns setof int as
$BODY$
begin
    return query
    delete from    my_table
    where          identifier = _identifier
    returning      identifier;
end
$BODY$
language plpgsql volatile strict;
```

This function accepts an identifier, deletes the corresponding row and returns the same identifier in case the delete was successful.

I am quite unsure if I should implement this as a set-returning function (like I did above) or a scalar function.

My reasoning for preferring set-returning function is the following:

1. In case of a scalar function, we will have a `NULL` return value in case the row could not be found (while we will have 0 rows in case of the set-returning function). Having to deal with `NULL`s is a pain.
2. I'm working with sets (SQL is all about sets), so it makes sense to just keep doing that.
3. Also, I prefer returning the identifier (`1 row`: successful, `0 rows`: not successful) instead of a `boolean` (`true`: successful, `false`: not successful), as it would allow constructs such as:

```
with d(id) as
(
    select * from my_table_delete(1234)
)
insert into log_table(id, action)
select      d.id, 'DELETE'
from        d;
```

If I were to return a `boolean`, the statement above could become less elegant.

I'm interested whether those arguments make sense. I'm quite new to the embedding logic into the database, so I'm not sure if I am addressing this correctly.

What do you think?

On a slightly related note, I also wonder if I should define the function as following:

```
create function my_table_delete(_identifier int)
    returns table (identifier int)
as ...
```

This gives the output row's column a name, which is even more convenient to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's assert that *manipulating a single row*  is positively guaranteed by a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `my_table.identifier`. Else it should be a table function to begin with.

Next: Should you write a function for such a simple `DELETE` at all? Or use the plain `DELETE` instead? Barely longer and less overhead. (Maybe your actual function is more sophisticated ...)

Then, while your function is that simple, a plain SQL function might serve:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_table_delete(_identifier int)
  RETURNS TABLE(identifier int)
$func$
   DELETE FROM my_table t
   WHERE  t.identifier = _identifier
   RETURNING t.identifier;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Also using `RETURNS TABLE` like you pondered: Note the table-qualified column name to avoid conflicts. All function parameters (including columns of a `RETURNS TABLE` clause) are visible in SQL commands in the function body (in PL/pgSQL as well as in SQL functions). You need to avoid conflicts between column names and parameters.

An SQL function has less overhead. But if you call the function many times in the same session, the PL/pgSQL variant may actually be faster since it manages SQL statements like prepared statements, meaning the query plan is saved and reused if some preconditions are met. Then again: much of the same effect is achieved with prepared statements. See:

- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/function-performance/8189#8189)
- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/939860)
- [Select column values linked to exact set of values in another column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133700/select-column-values-linked-to-exact-set-of-values-in-another-column/133738#133738)

As to your ***reasoning***:

*1.* If you don't want to deal with `NULL`, then the case is settled. Make it a table function. But you may have to deal with `NULL` after all: Various query constructs (have to) convert "no row" to NULL.

*2.* sounds like an argument, but is just a logical fallacy. Does not carry weight.

*3.* If it's your personal *preference*, then the case is settled again. Can't argue with that. But a data-modifying CTE would work with the scalar function just as well:

```
WITH d(id) AS (
   SELECT my_table_delete(1234)
   )
INSERT INTO log_table(id, action)
SELECT  d.id, 'DELETE'
FROM    d
WHERE   d.id IS NOT NULL;
```

In summary: go with `RETURNS TABLE`, but it hardly matters for the given case.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I want to add that the functions are indeed a bit complexer, I just posted a simple delete function for brevity. Though, all functions could be written as a single SQL query (so far), but I am writing them as `plpgsql` functions anyway. All those functions are `volatile`, so they cannot be inlined anyway. I learned (though I cannot find the source anymore) that one should prefer `plpgsql` functions when the body cannot be inlined, as the planner behaves more optimal this way.